# Sorting LocalDateTime

Tags: java, sorting, datetime, jodatime, java-time

How to sort `LocalDateTime` objects?

I tried the following:

```
Comparator<Data> comparator = new Comparator<Data>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final data o1, final data o2) {
        if (o1.getDate()== null || o2.getDate() == null)
            return 0;
        return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
    }
};

Collections.sort(comments, comparator);
```

After testing I think it sorts according to the date, but is the time part (HH:MM:SS) ignored?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - ideally following Java naming conventions. (It appears that `data` is the name of both a type and a variable in your sample code - that's *incredibly* confusing.) I'd also suggest that if `getDate()` is a method returning a `LocalDateTime`, that's pretty poorly named...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both JodaTime and JDK 8 `LocalDateTime` classes implement the `Comparable` interface, so you can sort them using their natural order. Just do

```
Collections.sort(data);
```

Comment: the data is ArrayList ,,sorry my bad

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar If this Answer resolves your Question, please accept it. Hit the big empty check mark found by the up-vote and down-vote buttons.

Comment: Also mind that this is a Void method, so `data` is immediately changed. No need to reassign the result.

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways to do it.
If date property is under nested object then use comparator as follows

```
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
 return obj2.getInnerObj().getLocalDateTime().compareTo(obj1.getInnerObj().getLocalDateTime());  }
```

If date property at the property of object then

```
List<Object> sortedList = objectList.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object :: getLocalDateTime).reversed())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you showed how to sort based on a property (Object.getLocalDateTime)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [isAfter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) and [isBefore()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-). Click for the Docs.
And maybe try to work on your indentation, I was a bit uncertain as to what is inside the if clause. Maybe even try to use curly braces {} even fore one-liners, but that's a matter of personal preference.